# Pthreads_create function that create threads

Tags: c

I was asked to create a program that starts from the command line with an arg that defines how many threads that shall be created, and every thread that been created shall print out its number. I have just started with the threading so please bear with me!

I know learn how to create threads but only predefine nr in the program but how to take the arg from user input? i don't really know how to go about the problem.

Comment: This link would give a good overview for threads. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 1):

The argument can be taken from the entry point of the C application. In the following example, I check if the argument count is 2. The first argument is the name of the program itself, the second being the count of threads you'd like to create.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Convert the string (char *) to an int with a base of 10
    int threads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        // Create thread
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
// Convert the string (char *) to an int with a base of 10
    long  int threads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    

    pthread_t threadsTOcreate [threads];
    

    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {

        pthread_create(&threadsTOcreate[i], NULL,NULL, &threads);
        printf("my number is %d",i);
    }
    
// wait until thread is done
    for (int i = 0; i < threads ; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threadsTOcreate[i], NULL);
    }
    
    return 0;
}